# how to make social login with DRF as backend and angularjs as frontend and DRF return jwt token for further interaction

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, google-signin, django-socialauth

**I am using angularjs as frontend and djnago rest frame(DRF) as backend. I want to make social login for my site.**

## Requirements

1. User logs in using the app to FB/Google.
2. FB/Google returns an access_token.
3. The app sends this access_token to Django backend using POST
   request.
4. Django Backends find the user associated to this FB account or
   creates a new one using first name, last name and email from FB
   account.
5. Django returns a JWT token for further authentication.
6. The JWT is saved on the browser as cookies.
7. Next the app uses this JWT to authenticate the user and then no more
   FB log in is necessary.

**pls help me how i make this..**

Comment: sorry for this .i changed the question .now u can help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend  you use [Sattelizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) is an angulajs library to use JWT with social logins
and here is an example [with python](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/python/app.py)  (the example uses Flask but you can apply the same logic in django)

I used this in django

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from modules.Pacientes.models import Paciente
from modules.Doctores.models import Doctor
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, parse_qsl
from django.conf import settings
import json
import requests
from .utils import *
import uuid

JWT_PAYLOAD = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
JWT_ENCODE = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER


class AuthGoogle(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        data = dict(client_id=request.data['clientId'],
                    redirect_uri=request.data['redirectUri'],
                    client_secret=settings.GOOGLE_SECRET,
                    code=request.data['code'],
                    grant_type='authorization_code')
        print(data)
        print(settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)
        # Obteniendo Access Token
        r = requests.post(settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, data=data)
        token = json.loads(r.text)
        print(token)
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token['access_token'])}

        # Obteniendo datos de perfil

        r = requests.get(settings.PEOPLE_API_URL, headers=headers)

        profile = json.loads(r.text)

        print(profile['email'])

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=profile['email'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = None

        if user:
            payload = JWT_PAYLOAD(user)
            token = JWT_ENCODE(payload)
            return Response({'token': token}, status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=profile['given_name'], email=profile["email"], password="nexo2016")
            paciente = Paciente(user=user, pic_profile=profile['picture'], google_sub=profile['sub'])
            paciente.save()
            send_email_welcome(user)
            payload = JWT_PAYLOAD(user)
            token = JWT_ENCODE(payload)
            return Response({'token': token}, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


class AuthFacebook(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        data = dict(client_id=request.data['clientId'],
                    redirect_uri=request.data['redirectUri'],
                    client_secret=settings.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
                    code=request.data['code'],
                    )
        r = requests.get(settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL_FACEBOOK, params=data)
        access_token = json.loads(r.text)
        print(r.text)
        r = requests.get(settings.GRAPH_API_URL, params=access_token)
        print(r.text)
        profile = json.loads(r.text)

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=profile['email'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = None

        if user:
            payload = JWT_PAYLOAD(user)
            token = JWT_ENCODE(payload)
            return Response({'token': token}, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=profile['name'], email=profile['email'],
                                            first_name=profile['first_name'], last_name=profile['last_name'])
            paciente = Paciente(user=user,
                                pic_profile='https://graph.facebook.com/' + profile['id'] + '/picture?type=normal',
                                facebook_id=profile['id'])
            paciente.save()
            send_email_welcome(user)
            payload = JWT_PAYLOAD(user)
            token = JWT_ENCODE(payload)
            return Response({'token': token}, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(request.data, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

I hope this could help you

Comment: thanks Edwin ...this is helpfull for me